# mod_rewrite redirect any domain except principal domain to the principal domain

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some rules as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

I would like to make the rewrite condition match ANY domain OTHER than the domain `www.domain.com` . How can I do this without explicitly make a `RewriteCond` for each case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negation

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```